Liferay SPA loader is moving from left to right
I am using liferay SPA loader when loading a resource. I have moved from Liferay 7.2 to Liferay 7.4.112 but the loader is moving from left to right because of the given property.

animation : shift-rightwards 1s ease-in-out infinite;

I am no where using this property, its appearing by default.
Is there a way to make it stop.


Which browser are you using? Can you replicate this on multiple browsers/pc's?

I am using Chrome and Firefox. This issue can be produced in multiple envs. @KristofMols

I've seen this happening with the technique that was documented here: https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/for-a-more-conspicuous-spa-loader - I'm assuming you introduced this loading-indicator some time in the past, because otherwise the spinner is not part of OOTB Liferay. Where you introduced this code is hard to say, but it seems to end up on the page

@OlafKock Yes, I have included this with Liferay 7.2 but after migration it is look like this. I still want this loader but it is not stopping to move from left to right.

Your question is "is there a way to make it stop?" - And yes, there is: Remove the CSS code that obviously needs to be updated. For anything else, you should provide a [mcve] and also check [ask].
